# Check if field is a substring of a longer string with MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to find a way to return a document based on wether or not a field is a substring of a given string.

I got a prototype working that basically fetches everything from the collection and then does the needed logic in code. In code I can find what I want by iterating over every document and then returning a document based on `search.includes(field)`. This is obviously not an ideal solution as fetching every document in a collection is an expensive operation that won't scale well.

Next thing I did was looking at text search using MongoDB indexes. This kind of works but it returns documents even if the field isn't a complete substring of the search.

Is there any way I can construct a query that checks if a field on a document is an exact substring of a given string?

As an example, here's three documents similar to those in my collection:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5b893f36e7e6ab1a88f87b39"),
    "trigger": "hello",
    "response": "World"
}

{
    "_id": ObjectId("5b6ca6169cc009573bbc3571"),
    "trigger": "stackoverflow",
    "response": "Is awesome!"
}

{
    "_id": ObjectId("5b6ca6169cc009573bbc3571"),
    "trigger": "foo bar",
    "response": "barfoo"
}
```

These are some cases with the output I expect:

The search strings `stack` or `stackexchange` should not return any documents as there is no trigger field which is a perfect substring of those.

The string `hello stackexchange` should get you only the first document as the trigger field is a substring of the search string.

The string `hello stackoverflow` would get you both documents as they both have a trigger field which is a substring of the search string.

**EDIT:** The query also has to deal with the fact that the trigger field may contain spaces. So the string `foo bar foobar` should match the last document but the string `foo` should not.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Can you add couple of sample documents including expected result ?

Comment: @Veeram I've updated my question with some documents and expected behavior.

Comment: I'm iffy on the query string design.   What if the query string is "foo bar foo foo bar foo"?    Which spaces are delimiters and which are not?  Could you work with an array approach for the query, e.g.  ["foo bar","foo","bar"]?

Comment: @BuzzMoschetti Well, as long as the trigger field of the document is a substring of the the query string, it should match. So your example should yield the last document if you were to use the set of documents from the question. The query should ideally regard a space as any other character. I suppose I could split the query string up into an array but I don't see then how I would match the trigger field against that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a quite a bit of trial and error, I've found a way to achieve what I wanted. By using `$indexOfBytes` in a `$gt`, I was able to check if trigger existed as a substring in the search string by seeing if the result of `$indexOfBytes` was greater than -1. Here is my final Mongoose query:

```
Collection.find({
    $expr: {
        $gt: [
            {
                $indexOfBytes: [
                    search,
                    "$trigger"
                ]
            },
            -1
        ]
    }
});
```